# take one of the same elements in different strings

Tags: python, arrays, element, repeat, difference

I want to combine the three different series I have. I also need to provide singularity for each element. Output order is not important.Example 3 arrays:

```
a=["apple","banana","orange"]
b=["apple","banana"]
c=["cherry","grappe"]
```

result

```
result=["apple","banana","orange","cherry","grappe"]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify what the order of expected output is - you accepted an answer that explicitely gives a different order...

Comment: output order is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain` then convert to set to remove duplicates and then convert back to list (done a sort too):

```
import itertools
a=["apple","banana","orange"]
b=["apple","banana"]
c=["cherry","grappe"]
d = sorted(list(set(list(itertools.chain(a,b,c)))))
print(d)
```

Comment: The expected output has the output sorted by order of appearance, this would sort in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` and do like this:

```
a=["apple","banana","orange"]
b=["apple","banana"]
c=["cherry","grappe"]

result = list(set(a + b + c))

>>> result = ["apple","banana","orange","cherry","grappe"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
b = ["apple", "banana"]
c = ["cherry", "grappe"]

lst = list(set(a + b + c))
print(lst)
```

```
['banana', 'apple', 'cherry', 'grappe', 'orange']
```

Check out the docs for [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Is it any different from my answer?

Comment: Other than detailing where to find the documentation for set, and being 30s after yours, nope, doesn't seem like it. :)

Comment: You can edit my answer adding doc link to have only one answer if that's fine with you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the order of first appearance, as your sample output suggests, one way is to create a dict with your data as keys, taking advantage of the fact that dicts are ordered since Python 3.7:

```
from itertools import chain

a = ["apple","banana","orange"]
b = ["apple","banana"]
c = ["cherry","grappe"]

d = {key: None for key in chain(a, b, c)}
result = list(d.keys())

print(result)
# ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'cherry', 'grappe']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
b = ["apple", "banana"]
c = ["cherry", "grappe"]
result = a + b + c  # marge all lsit
result = list(dict().fromkeys(result))  # remove duplicate
print(result)
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to get rid of duplicates:

```
list(set(a+b+c))
```